# Error - input text mangled

Tags: html

I have a website that works correctly in my notebook as image 02. In another notebook , the text that is entered in the input is mangled like image01.

The image link follows because I'm newbie and still do not have enough points to post the image .

http://oi61.tinypic.com/2uppo9c.jpg

Is there anything I can do to fix this problem ?
I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate with asp.net 4.5.

Answer (score 0):

This could simply be a side effect of the screen resolution.
Maybe the resolution is causing the text to appear mangled....

Try viewing the same page on a friends pc/laptop.